# C++ Recursive Function Infinite Loop

Tags: c++, function, recursion, infinite-loop

I have a function which takes an int value from another function. When I type a wrong int value it works as intended (calls the same function recursively & lets me enter a new number) but when I type anything other than an int (a, %, etc) it calls the function recursively but gets stuck in an infinite loop. Any help/insight would be great as I am in the learning stages of C++ Programming.

Here is my Full code snippet (49 Lines)

To summarize what I am asking is how would I properly go about displaying an error and returning back to the Main Menu without triggering the infinite loop when a non-int value is given.

```
int MainMenu();
void MainMenuSelection(int x);

int main()
{
    MainMenuSelection(MainMenu());
    return 0;
}

int MainMenu() {
    int selection;
    std::cout << "C++ Tutorials Main Menu\n";
    std::cout << "----------------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout << "1 - Chapter #1\n";
    std::cout << "2 - Chapter #2\n";
    std::cout << "3 - Chapter #3\n";
    std::cout << "----------------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout << "Please enter a cooresponding value: ";
    std::cin >> selection;

    if (std::cin.fail()) {
        std::cout << "Input must be an integer";
    }
    else {
        return selection;
    }
}

void MainMenuSelection(int x) {

    if (x == 1) {
        std::cout << "\nChapter #1 is unavailable.\n";
        std::cout << std::string(22, '\n');
        MainMenuSelection(MainMenu());
    }
    else if (x == 2) {
        std::cout << std::string(2, '\n');
        ChTwoMenuSelection(ChTwoMenu());
    }
    else if (x == 3) {
        std::cout << std::string(2, '\n');
        ChThreeMenuSelection(ChThreeMenu());
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "\nThere was an incorrect value submitted.";
        std::cout << std::string(22, '\n');
        MainMenuSelection(MainMenu());
    }

}
```

Comment: If a function declared to return a value, but it doesn't actually do that, then you have *undefined behavior*. In your case, there is an execution path where you *don't'* return anything from the `MainMenu` function.

Comment: Also, why are you using recursive calls instead of loops? In your case loops would make more sense.

Comment: As 'Some programmer dude' said: Here you are **not** returning anything but you have to: `if (std::cin.fail()) { std::cout << "Input must be an integer"; }`.

Comment: Lastly, if you enter something which can not be parsed as an `int` by the `std::cin` input operator, then that input will be left in the input buffer and will be read *again* next time you attempt input. This is the cause of the infinite loop. I suggest you look into [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) and [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream), or [`std::istream::ignore`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore).

Comment: You need to use Loop .. that's more appropriate in your case .. You need to use (do while) loop to handle that .. Take your input in character and check if user input any character esle 1,2,3 you can simply came out of that ..

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - Thanks for the explanation, so I changed it so that when 'cin.fail' is triggered it returns the int value 0. I also updated my 'MainMenuSelection' funtion to handle the int value 0 with an appropriate error message. I am currently looking into the following fixes you mentioned with getline / istringstream & istringstream::ignore to fix the input buffer issues!

Comment: @UmerFarooq I have not looked into do...while loops yet as I am following the learncpp.com tutorials. Thanks for the suggestion and I will most likely change this code once I get to that point and understand them more in depth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `MainMenuSelection( int x )` requires an int. The function call in the main function thinks it gets this by calling a function which should return an int namely `int MainMenu()`. But this function does not do what you should expect from a function which has been declared in this way. You should make sure that a function should ALWAYS return the value (except for a void of course).

There are static code analyzers like Cppcheck which can help you to analyse your code and find possible problems like the one you stated above.

Another tip would be to think about what happens when you execute the code. Especially when your code is still quite small you can manually go through the statements to see what path it takes, so you can find out where the program fails.